# Median stack profile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, profile

I am trying to create a median or average stack profile on a DEM in QGIS but I can't find any tool or plugin for it. This feature is implemented in GMT [1](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/doc/latest/gallery/ex33.html)). 
Can anybody give me a hint of how it can be done in QGIS?